# Why my v-date-picker doesn't show dates of 2021 and after?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vuetify.js

I don't know why my v-date-picker only shows the allowed date of the current year.
The allowed dates is an array that i receive from backend.
And it works perfectly for the current year but for the future years it doesn't work as it should.
Here is my v-date-picker code :

```
          <v-date-picker
            locale="it"
            first-day-of-week="1"
            :min="pastDates"
            :allowedDates="allowedDates"
            color="red"
            v-model="date"
            @update:picker-date="pickerUpdate($event)"
            @input="menu_date = false"
            @change="checkDate()"
          ></v-date-picker>
```

and here there are the function which allow dates

```
 allowedDates(a) {
  return this.availableDates.includes(a);
},

pickerUpdate: function (val) {
  let totalDay = moment(val, "YYYY-MM").daysInMonth();
  let availableDates = [];
       let x = new Date();
    let year = x.getFullYear();
    
  for (let i = 0; i <= totalDay; i++) {
    
    let date = moment()
      .month(val.split("-")[1] - 1)
      .date(i)
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log("anno corrente in date :",year , " in moment:", moment(date).year());
    if (
      moment(date).day() !== 0 &&
      moment(date).day() !== 6  &&
      this.date_bloccate.filter(f=>f==date).length==0      
    )     
   availableDates.push(date)
     if(moment(this.date).day()==0||moment(this.date).day()==6)
     {
       console.log("date_bloccate:",this.date_bloccate)
       this.snackbar=true;
       this.colore_snack="orange";
       this.messaggio_snackbar="Attenzione selezionare una data valida!"
     }else{
       this.date_bloccate.forEach(e=>{
         if(this.date==e)
         {
            this.snackbar=true;
            this.colore_snack="orange";
            this.messaggio_snackbar="Attenzione selezionare una data valida!"
            this.invalid_date=true;
         }
       })
     }
  }
     this.availableDates = availableDates;
  this.allowedDates();
},
```

I am using moment js.

EDIT:Ok i found the problem, basically i was using totalDay that gets the actual day in month, now i set in the for loop 1095 instead of totalDay, soo whit this change i can take dates for three years, is there a way to automatically get all days of all year to check?

Comment: maybe because you're calling `this.allowedDates()` but that function needs a value... BTW, never use single char variables, only `i` in a for loop, try not to write code like that, helps no one from "this" side 

Comment: Ok gotcha the function step, but what do you mean with never using single char variables. I am not using it

Comment: `allowedDates(a) { ... }` ... I would name that `a` with something a bit more meaningful 

Comment: Oh you mean that, i found tha code on a git section to use moment with allow dates, yep sorry my bad